# How to pass a custom type as an observation to DQN agent using PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, reinforcement-learning, dqn

I want to pass a custom state (observation) to my agent, which includes an array of custom-type objects ( of a class I defined called Task), battery level (integer), resources (integer), and channel gain (integer), when I pass the described state it gives me this error "must be real number, not Task" in the following line

```
state = T.tensor([observation],dtype=T.float32).to(self.q_eval.device)
```

How can I fix it ?

```
def select_action(self, observation,episode):
        #update epsilon 
        epsilon  = self.INITIAL_EPSILON - episode * (self.INITIAL_EPSILON - self.FINAL_EPSILON) / self.max_episode
        M = observation.shape[0]   #the number of observations's features 
        state = T.tensor([observation],dtype=T.float32).to(self.q_eval.device)
        actions = self.q_eval.forward(state)
        a_hat=T.argmax(T.squeeze(actions),dim=1).detach().numpy()
        random_index = np.array(np.random.uniform(size = (M)) < epsilon, dtype = np.int32)
        random_action = np.random.randint(0, high = self.n_actions , size = (M))
        action_set = np.vstack([a_hat, random_action])
        action = action_set[random_index, range(M)] #[M]
        return  action
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `state = T.tensor([observation],dtype=T.float32).to(self.q_eval.device)` Here you specified that you want every element within the tensor to have a datatype of `float32`. Since you stated that `observation` includes a custom class, it cannot be casted to a floating point.

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html This link shows you what data types are allowed when constructing a torch tensor. Generally only real numbers are allowed since it is necessary when calculating the gradients for back propagation.

You can probably encode the attributes within your custom class into real numbers. For instance:

```py
class Task:
    def __init__(self, attr1: float, attr2: int):
        self.attr1 = attr1
        self.attr2 = attr2
    
    def encodeToTensor(self):
        return torch.tensor([self.attr1, self.attr2], dtype=torch.float32)
```

Then you can concatenate this tensor with the rest of the real numbers to form an input tensor, given that you can actually encode the necessary attributes into real numbers somehow.